# Bash time behaves weird

Tags: bash, time

Why this doesn't work?

```
$ time sleep 1 2>&1 | grep real

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.001s

$ ofile=time.out
$ for x in {1..2}; do time sleep 1 ${x}> ${ofile} && test -s ${ofile} && echo '## OK' || echo '## NOK'; done

real    0m2.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.000s
## NOK

real    0m3.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.000s
## NOK
```

According to `man time`:

> When command finishes, time writes a message to standard error giving timing statistics about this program run.

Where did I get it wrong? It also seems weird that with each iteration time grows?

```
$ command -V time
time is a shell keyword

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

***EDIT***

I tried what was suggested in the comments:

```
$ command time sleep 1
bash: time: command not found
```

Also tested it on the Debian9 system:

```
$ command -V time 
time is a shell keyword

$ command time sleep 1
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1844maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+76minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ time sleep 1 |& grep real

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: The bash `time` builtin appears to output directly to your tty: this still shows output: `time sleep 1 >/dev/null 2>&1` -- try using the `time` command: `command time sleep 1 2>output.file`

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: For bash builtins, use `help` not `man`. `help time` will tell you that the whole pipeline is measured. That's why you can not catch its result by piping through grep, unless using braces or parentheses like Stephen Harris did in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388216/203203).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command `time sleep 1 ${x}` effectively runs `time sleep 1 1` and then `time sleep 1 2`.

The `bash` builtin `time` command takes those two values and sleeps for both of them.

So `sleep 1 1` is the same as `sleep 2` and `sleep 1 2` is the same as `sleep 3`.

With the builtin `time` command, things don't quite work the same way as normal and so `time sleep 2>...` is interpreted closer to `time ( sleep 2>...)`.

So instead

```
( time sleep 1 ) 2>&1 | grep real
```

Comment: Just curious, did you came to conclusion of `time sleep 1 1` by trying something like `set -x x=1; time sleep 1 ${x}> test`, or there's something that I don't understand about `Bash`?

Comment: Hmm, your loop sets x=1 then x=2 and `${x}` is set each time.  So it's literally running `sleep 1 1` then `sleep 1 2`.  That's just how loops work.  For example; `for a in hello there; do echo ${a}; done` will return two lines; "hello" and "there".  Your loop is just the same.

Comment: But why it does not redirect `${x}>` properly? So in the first iteration it should be `1> file` (file descriptor 1 `STDOUT` to file), in the other iteration it should be  `2> file` (file descriptor 2 `STDERR` to file), or is it not possible to specify file descriptors in the variable? Also in your answer you show `time sleep 2>...`, when it actually should be `time sleep 1 2>...`

Comment: That's just not how shell parsing works.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, why in this situation setting file descriptor in the variable does not work?

Comment: Bash parsing means that redirection occurs before variable expansion, so the parser doesn't _see_ `2>`; it just sees `>`.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser